# codeigniter alter Common.php functions

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, logging

I'm trying to customize the logging functionality of codeigniter.  I found this forum thread which describes exactly what I need:
http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/139997/
But I want to do that without altering core files/classes.

I"m trying to alter the log_message function.  I've already extended the CI_Log class and that is working well, but now I'm trying to alter log_message() which resides in system/core/Common.php.  It isn't actually a class so I can't extend it, it just appears to be a collection of useful functions.  I tried redeclaring log_message() and placing it in application/core/Common.php, but that doesn't appear to work.  Any ideas how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the function you actually want to alter is `write_log()`, correct me if I'm wrong.  You can do this by extending the function within `application\libraries\MY_Log.php`.

I have the following script in my MY_Log.php which emails me any time an error is thrown:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/* Extends the logging class to send an email when an error is triggered */

class MY_Log extends CI_Log {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function write_log($level = 'error', $msg, $php_error = FALSE, $additional, $additional2)

    {   
        if ($this->_enabled === FALSE)
        {
        return FALSE;
        }

         $level = strtoupper($level);

        if ( ! isset($this->_levels[$level]) OR ($this->_levels[$level] > $this->_threshold))
        {
        return FALSE;
        }

        $filepath = $this->_log_path.'log-'.date('Y-m-d').'.php';
        $message  = '';

        if ( ! file_exists($filepath))
        {
        $message .= "<"."?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?".">\n\n";
        }

        if ( ! $fp = @fopen($filepath, FOPEN_WRITE_CREATE))
        {
        return FALSE;
        }

        $message .= $level.' '.(($level == 'INFO') ? ' -' : '-').' '.date($this->_date_fmt). ' --> '.$msg."\n";

        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
        fwrite($fp, $message);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);

        @chmod($filepath, FILE_WRITE_MODE);
        return TRUE;
    }

}
```

If you're not looking to extend the write function, you will need to extend one of the other log functions.

Comment: I've already extended write_log() to do what I need it to do.  I was hoping I could extend the global function log_message() so that I anytime I call it I can pass it a log name and it would log the message to that specific log.  I suppose I could always just call write_log() directly though, instead of going through log_message()...

Comment: @Erreth - I believe log_message() utilizes write_log().  So, when log_message is called, the call will still flow through write_log, allowing you to perform whatever additional function is needed.

Comment: @Erreth - What exactly are you looking to change? If I had a few more details I may be able to assist a little more.

Comment: Did you read the forum thread I posted?  I'm trying to alter log_message() so that I can pass it an additional parameter -> the name of the log file.  That way I can log different events to different files.  I'd like to be able to pass log_message() another parameter, so that it goes and calls my extended version of write_log() passing along the log name.

Comment: @Erreth - If you don't want to modify any core files, you will need to copy the entire logging function into your `MY_Log.php`.  Then DON'T call `parent::write_log($level, $msg, $php_error);` at the end of the extension.  I will modify my code to show you what I mean.

Comment: @Erreth - The easiest way - albeit kind of sloppy - is to just slightly modify that core function to do what you want it to do.

Comment: Ya, I think I may just end up modifying the core function.  Hope it doesn't get messed up in upgrades...I'll just have to remember about it.

Comment: @Erreth - Upgrading is really where you may get caught off-guard, but you would likely still need to check through all of your extensions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A helper function could work here.  You'd have to use it instead of log_message().

Here's what I did:

in application/helpers I created 'new_log_helper.php' (helpers have to end in _helper.php)
I wanted this to add log entries into the database and to track by process (that way I know where to look in the code).

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Custom Logging Interface
 *
 * Add log entries to a log table on the db and track process name
 *
 * @access  public
 * @return  void
 */
if ( ! function_exists('new_log')) {
    function new_log($level = 'error', $message, $process, $php_error = FALSE)
    {
        if (config_item('log_threshold') == 0) {
            return;
        }

        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->model('new_log','logger', TRUE);
        $CI->logger->add_event($process, $level, $message);

        log_message($level, $process.': '.$message, $php_error);
    }
}
```

Then when you need it use it like this:

```
$this->load->helper('new_log');
...
new_log('debug','Something happened','Stack overflow answer');
```

Anyway I know your issue was years ago but I was looking so maybe someone else is too.